# How to remove whitespaces while converting string to array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to convert input like this:

```
5
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   3   1   4   1   -3
1   2   -3  4   3   9
2   -1  3   -1  -4  -1
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and save each digit (single line) to array and after that print content of array on the console. In my example array should have length=6. I don't want any white spaces in my array. I can't tell you how many whitespaces are between each digit. At the end I would like to get output like this:

```
123456
13141-3
12-3439
2-13-1-4-1
000000
```

I tried to write some code but it doesn't give me good answer as I would have liked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using c = System.Console;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int t = int.Parse(c.ReadLine());


        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
        {

            string x;
            x = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] l = x.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
            {
                c.Write(l[i]);
            }
            c.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work properly" doesn't tell us anything.  Be specific.

Comment: What doesn't work with what you have?  It's not the most effective way but it looks like it should have worked.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: program compiles well, but doesn't give me right output as i showed

Comment: What does it return instead?

Comment: Sry i see now that when i copy the input which i written here program shows output correctly but when i copy input form this page http://pl.spoj.com/problems/JWSPLIN/ (polish page with exercise) my program doesnt gives correct output

Comment: When you copy it's tabs not spaces, try `string[] l = x.Split(new char[] { '\t' });`

Comment: Do you understand Polish? That exercise is asking you to determine whether the points (presumably parsed as pairs) are [collinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity), outputting "TAK" (yes) if they are, and "NIE" (no) if they're not.

Comment: You can write an answer and i give point for you i missed it XD

Comment: This question isn't helpful to anyone. It should be closed.

Comment: i agree wth you :) sry for problem, my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you're copying is separated by tabs not spaces, so you can change the split character to `\t` and your code should do as you expect.

```
string[] l = x.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
```